# Cassandra Error Handling

Tags: cassandra

The session.execute() portion of my Cassandra client does not prompt any error handling prompt in eclipse.

```
session.execute(batch);
```

Should I manually do try catch .

```
try
{
session.execute(batch); 
}
catch(Exception e)
{
// Handle error here
}
```

If yes, Should I handle [each error](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/exceptions/package-summary.html) related to query execution separately?

Comment: The relevant exceptions are documented in the javadoc api: http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/Session.html#execute%28com.datastax.driver.core.Statement%29

Comment: Why there is no throws prompt in Eclipse? If I handled the exceptions throws from execute method    1) NoHostAvailableException 2) 
QueryExecutionException 3) 
QueryValidationException 4) UnsupportedFeatureException what will happen if other exception like InvalidType exceptions occurred?

Answer (score 4):

`NoHostAvailableException`, `QueryExecutionException`, `QueryValidationException`, and `UnsupportedFeatureException` all extend [`DriverException`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/exceptions/DriverException.html) which is a [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) which is an unchecked exception.   From the javadoc for `RuntimeException`:

> RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions. Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary.

This is why eclipse doesn't give you a compiler error when you don't handle session.execute with a try catch or throws declaration in your method signature.